# How to call a SOAP web service on Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am having a lot of trouble finding good information on how to call a standard SOAP/WSDL web service with Android. All I've been able to find are either very convoluted documents and references to "kSoap2" and then some bit about parsing it all manually with [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML). OK, that's fine, but it's 2008, so I figured there should be some good library for calling standard web services.

The web service is just basically one created in [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans). I would like to have IDE support for generating the plumbing classes. I just need the easiest/most-elegant way to contact a [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) based web service from an Android-based phone.

Comment: Here is very good link on using SOAP in android: [How to Call Web Service in Android Using SOAP](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/)

Comment: If somebody previously familiar with MS VS, using Mono for Android will solve many problems with data services and web services, everything is simple and fast development.
Also who is not familiar with C# (code very similar to Java), all library has the same methods, some functions replaced on properties, so names almost the same and who wrote before on Java for android can very easy using their experience to write c# code.

Comment: Have a look at the below Link it has a detailed Eaxample on accessing a webservice in Android Using Ksoap2 [Accessing a Webservice from Android](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-web-service-access-tutorial.html)

Comment: I believe this is possible with Xamarin/C# using .Net Core. see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/25/announcing-wcf-connected-service-for-net-core-rc2-and-asp-net-core-rc2/

Comment: This [tool](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) by Spring looks promising.

Comment: More pointless mess from mods...

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Android does not provide any sort of SOAP library. You can either write your own, or use something like [kSOAP 2](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/). As you note, others have been able to compile and use kSOAP2 in their own projects, but I haven't had to.

Google has shown, to date, little interest in adding a SOAP library to Android. My suspicion for this is that they'd rather support the current trends in Web Services toward REST-based services, and using JSON as a data encapsulation format. Or, using XMPP for messaging. But that is just conjecture.

XML-based web services are a slightly non-trivial task on Android at this time. Not knowing NetBeans, I can't speak to the tools available there, but I agree that a better library should be available. It is possible that the XmlPullParser will save you from using SAX, but I don't know much about that.

Comment: Yeah, I think I will have to build a REST proxy. It seems pretty strange that Google has no interest in providing SOAP support. I tried the kSoap method, it's really not even a serious alternative. It is, at best, an ugly had that requires much scouring of newsgroups.

Comment: The reason is probably that SOAP is very verbose and doesn't serve the constraints of mobile computing well.

Comment: This answer would be improved if someone could **suggest the best alternative** to calling web services with an Android App. Once people find this question and read it, that's what most of them will be looking for.

Comment: SOAP processing is also memory and processor intensive compared to a more concise format like JSON.

Comment: @MGOwen The best alternative I can see is a proxy. Implement a REST-ful interface that proxies the SOAP envelopes through WSDL2Java.

Comment: @MGOwen please check my answer, currently it is best and only alternative as customers get support for the license fees paid.

Comment: KSoap library can't manage huge request or response. All data is loaded on memory, so could happen that App crashes and OutOfMemory exception occurs.

Answer (score 99):

`org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient` comes in the Android SDK by default. That'll get you connected to the WSDL.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com/" + URL);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
```

Comment: Yeah, this would be the route where I would have to manually parse everything, I wouldn't get an object oriented approach.

Comment: You mean you wouldn't get a free lunch.  Manual parsing doesn't have anything to do with OO.  I could parse everything on paper with my most advanced tool being an HB1 pencil and it would still be OO.

Comment: I believe by OO the author meant Java-XML binding. What would be your next step in this approach to parse the response? And if it has hundreds of elements, organized in a tree structure?

Comment: BTW, I would expect at least an HTTP POST not a GET if you want to have any luck with SOAP. Also, where's the Accept and SOAPAction headers? If you really want to go commando it will take much more than these 4 lines to consume a SOAP service.

Comment: If I had my druthers I wouldn't use SOAP for a web serivce to start with.  I'd go RESTful with XML or better yet JSON.  You are writing a client on a mobile device.  Do you really want to use the device itself to parse WSDL, automatically create the supporting classes and then the proxy itself before even making its first web service call?  How often are you going to do this?  What's the application exactly? O.o

Comment: @NeilD: What if you were forced by circumstances to use SOAP, e.g. the webserver uses SOAP and you have not control over this?

Comment: @bjarkef: kSOAP 2 seems to be a popular choice, as per the answer above.  Although there's nothing innately unmanageable about consuming SOAP without it, it's just more work.  You could also write a proxy server and decouple the SOAP web service in question and your mobile client, but that may turn out to be a much larger task than simply adopting kSOAP or some other similar library.

Comment: Yeah, this is not really answering the OP's question.  Turns out to be useful to me (in my case, I don't even really care that much about the SOAP response, I just need to make sure the service is alive; so even though it's disappointing there's no built in SOAP library, a refresher in how to do a basic POST in Android is handy) but it's not really answering *this* question.

Comment: Is there any way to send XML headers without using ksoap?

Answer (score 60):

It's true that due to it's overhead SOAP is not the best choice for data exchange with mobile devices. However, you might find yourself in situation in which you do not control the format of server output.

So, if you have to stick with SOAP, there is a kSOAP2 library patched for Android here:
http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

Answer (score 31):

To call a web service from a mobile device (especially on an Android phone), I have used a very simple way to do it. I have not used any web service client API in attempt to call the web service. My approach is as follows to make a call.

1. Create a simple HTTP connection by
   using the Java standard API
   `HttpURLConnection`.
2. Form a SOAP request. (You can make
   help of SOAPUI to make a SOAP
   request.)
3. Set doOutPut flag as true.
4. Set HTTP header values like
   content-length, Content
   type, and User-agent. Do not forget 
   to set Content-length value as it is a mandatory.
5. Write entire the SOAP request to the output stream.
6. Call the method to make a connection and
   receive the response (In my case I used
   `getResonseCode`).
7. If your received response code as

   200. It means you are succeeded to call web service.
8. Now take an input stream on the same
   HTTP connection and receive the
   string object. This string object is
   a SOAP response.
9. If the response code is other than
   200 then take a `ErrorInput` stream on
   same HTTPobject and receive the
   error if any.
10. Parse the received response
     using SAXParser (in my case) or
     DOMParaser or any other parsing
     mechanism.

I have implemented this procedure for the Android phone, and it is successfully running. I am able to parse the response even if it is more than 700 KB.

Answer (score 29):

SOAP is an ill-suited technology for use on Android (or mobile devices in general) because of the processing/parsing overhead that's required.  A REST services is a lighter weight solution and that's what I would suggest.  Android comes with a SAX parser, and it's fairly trivial to use.  If you are absolutely required to handle/parse SOAP on a mobile device then I feel sorry for you, the best advice I can offer is just not to use SOAP.

Comment: There is a special place in hell for those who force developers to use SOAP services instead of REST API.

Answer (score 24):

About a year ago I was reading this thread trying to figure out how to do SOAP calls on Android - the suggestions to build my own using HttpClient resulted in me building my own SOAP library for Android:

[IceSoap](https://github.com/AlexGilleran/IceSoap)

Basically it allows you to build up envelopes to send via a simple Java API, then automatically parses them into objects that you define via XPath... for example:

```
<Dictionary>
    <Id></Id>
    <Name></Name>
</Dictionary>
```

Becomes:

```
@XMLObject("//Dictionary")
public class Dictionary {
    @XMLField("Id")
    private String id;

    @XMLField("Name")
    private String name;
}
```

I was using it for my own project but I figured it might help some other people so I've spent some time separating it out and documenting it. I'd really love it if some of your poor souls who stumble on this thread while googling "SOAP Android" could give it a go and get some benefit.

Comment: did you work with session Authentification on IceSoap ?

Answer (score 24):

> DON'T FORGET TO ADD ksoap2.jar in your project and also add the
>   INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest file

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WebserviceActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/";
    private static final String URL ="https://apitest.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx?wsdl"; 
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/AuthenticateTest";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "AuthenticateTest";
    private TextView lblResult;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        lblResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
        request.addProperty("name","44vmMAYrhjfhj66fhJN");
        request.addProperty("transactionKey","9MDQ7fghjghjh53H48k7e7n");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            //SoapPrimitive  resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            // SoapPrimitive  resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;


            lblResult.setText(resultsRequestSOAP.toString());
            System.out.println("Response::"+resultsRequestSOAP.toString());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error"+e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: HttpTransportSE  where can i get this class ??

Comment: Hello, i am using your code but i am getting following error, Response::AuthenticateTestResponse{AuthenticateTestResult=anyType{resultCode=Error; messages=anyType{MessagesTypeMessage=anyType{code=E00014; text=Merchant Authentication is required.; }; }; }; } can you help me please?

Comment: hi Amit i m also amit ..... Can u tell me how response we compare when  we got response is successful or not so how and what conditions to check response ......

Comment: how to add array in xml of request property?

Answer (score 21):

I had my tryst with KSOAP; I chose a rather simpler approach.

Given a WSDL file, create SOAP Request templates for each Request(for e.g.: using SOAP UI) and then substitute the values to be passed in code. POST this data to the service end point using DefaultHttpClient instance and get the response stream. Parse the Response Stream using an XML Pull parser.

Answer (score 18):

You can have a look at [WSClient++](http://wsclient.neurospeech.com/wsclient/java-android-blackberry/)

Comment: Finally a first useful answer after repeating either kSoap or SAX

Comment: I tried the demo version. Didn't work for me for a simple service. Is isn't worth spending so many $$$$$.

Answer (score 16):

I've created a new SOAP client for the Android platform. It is using a JAX-WS generated interface, but it is only a proof-of-concept so far.

If you are interested, please try the example and/or watch the source at [AndroidSOAP](http://wiki.javaforum.hu/display/ANDROIDSOAP/Home).

Comment: I had the pleasure to attend your presentation at JUM XVII. Budapest about this Android stuff. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 15):

If you can, go for JSON. Android comes with the complete org.json package

Answer (score 14):

Call **ksoap2** methods. It works very fine.

Set up the details, like

```
private static String mNAMESPACE=null;
private static String mURL=null;
public static Context context=null;
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

envelope.addMapping(mNAMESPACE, "UserCredentials",new UserCredendtials().getClass());
AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(mURL);
```

and then to get the result do

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
```

Answer (score 13):

I hope *[Calling a web service from Android](http://www.anddev.org/calling_a_web_service_from_android-t348.html)* helps.

Answer (score 11):

Few months ago I was working with jax-ws web service in j2ee application, There we were using [CXF wsdl2java](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) to generate WS client stub from the WSDL file and with those client stubs we consumed the web services. Few weeks ago, when I was trying to consume the web service in the same way in android platform I couldn't, because the android jar has not all the "jax-ws" supporting classes in it. That time I didn't find any such tool ( if I wasn't failed to google efficiently) to meet my requirement --

- Get the client stub from the WSDL.
- And call the Service with some argument (java business request
  object).
- Get the Response Business Object.

So, I developed my own [Android SOAP Client Generation Tool](http://code.google.com/p/android-ws-client/). Where you have to follow these steps :

- From WSDL Get WS Client Stub, Put it in your project.
- Say for Some Service "ComplexOperationService", Instantiate the
  Service, Get the Endpoint port and call the service method, and get the response from   the Web service :

eg:

```
ComplexOperationService service = new ComplexOperationService( );
ComplexOperation port= service.getComplexOperationPort();    
SomeComplexRequest request = --Get some complex request----;    
SomeComplexResp resp = port.operate( request  );
```

- You don't need to care about the service class/req/response classes or any other classes and the method as well, as you know its all are generated from WSDL.
- And of course you needn't be aware of the soap action/envelop/namespace etc. Just call the method as we, developers do all the time.

Comment: Do you know how to deal with Date? Apache CXF translate it to XMLGregorianCalendar which I am not able to create in Android.

Answer (score 9):

I am sure you could make a little SOAP client with [Axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Axis). [Axis installation instructions](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/install.html).

Comment: That would work only if axis were compatible with Android.  It's not (something about javax.* packages in the axis dependencies).

Answer (score 8):

I think *[Call SOAP Web Service from Android application](http://www.pjava.wordpress.com)*  will help you a lot.

Answer (score 6):

If you can use JSON, there is a whitepaper, a video and the sample.code in *[Developing Application Services with PHP Servers and Android Phone Clients](http://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/php-android)*.

Answer (score 6):

Follow these steps by the method SOAP

From the WSDL file,

- create SOAP Request templates for each Request.
- Then substitute the values to be passed in code.
- POST this data to the service end point using DefaultHttpClient instance.
- Get the response stream and finally
- Parse the Response Stream using an XML Pull parser.

Answer (score 5):

If you are having problem regarding calling Web Service in android then 
You can use below code to call the web service and get response. Make sure that your the web service return the response in **Data Table Format**..This code will help you if you using data from **SQL Server** database. If you using **MYSQL** you need to change one thing just replace word  **NewDataSet** from sentence `obj2=(SoapObject) obj1.getProperty("NewDataSet");` by **DocumentElement**

```
void callWebService(){ 

private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/"; // for wsdl it may be package name i.e http://package_name
private static final String URL = "http://localhost/sample/services/MyService?wsdl";
// you can use IP address instead of localhost
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Function_Name";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "urn:" + METHOD_NAME;

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("parm_name", prm_value);// Parameter for Method
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;// **If your Webservice in .net otherwise remove it**
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);// call the eb service
                                                                                                         // Method
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Next task is to get Response and format that response
    SoapObject obj, obj1, obj2, obj3;
    obj = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
    obj1 = (SoapObject) obj.getProperty("diffgram");
    obj2 = (SoapObject) obj1.getProperty("NewDataSet");

    for (int i = 0; i < obj2.getPropertyCount(); i++) { 
// the method getPropertyCount() and  return the number of rows
            obj3 = (SoapObject) obj2.getProperty(i);
            obj3.getProperty(0).toString();// value of column 1
            obj3.getProperty(1).toString();// value of column 2
            // like that you will get value from each column
        }
    }
```

If you have any problem regarding this you can write me..

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest checking out a very useful tool that helped me a lot. The guys
who take care of that project were very helpful, too.
www.wsdl2code.com/

Answer (score 4):

This is a working example of consuming SOAP web services in android.

**Note ::***DON'T FORGET TO ADD ksoap2.jar in your project and also add the INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest file*

```
public final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
public final String METHOD_NAME = "FahrenheitToCelsius";
public final String PROPERTY_NAME = "Fahrenheit";
public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius";
public final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";


private class TestAsynk extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                String.format("%.2f", Float.parseFloat(result)),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
                METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty(PROPERTY_NAME, params[0]);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                SOAP_ADDRESS);
        Object response = null;
        try {

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            response = envelope.getResponse();
            Log.e("Object response", response.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: please help me on this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573829/how-to-send-and-receive-soap-data-from-webservice-to-google-app-engine

Answer (score 4):

Please download and add SOAP library file with your project
File Name : **ksoap2-android-assembly-3.4.0-jar-with-dependencies**

Clean the application and then start program

Here is the code for SOAP service call

```
    String SOAP_ACTION = "YOUR_ACTION_NAME";
    String METHOD_NAME = "YOUR_METHOD_NAME";
    String NAMESPACE = "YOUR_NAME_SPACE";
    String URL = "YOUR_URL";
    SoapPrimitive resultString = null;

    try {
        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        addPropertyForSOAP(Request);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
        resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

        Log.i("SOAP Result", "Result Celsius: " + resultString);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("SOAP Result", "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    if(resultString != null) {
        return resultString.toString();
    }
    else{
        return "error";
    }
```

The results may be JSONObject or JSONArray Or String

For your better reference,
https://trinitytuts.com/load-data-from-soap-web-service-in-android-application/

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You may perform soap call as post over http with certain headers.
I solved this question without additional libraries like ksoap2
Here is live code getting orders from soap service

```
private static HashMap<String,String> mHeaders = new HashMap<>();

static {
    mHeaders.put("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate");
    mHeaders.put("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml");
    mHeaders.put("Host", "35.15.85.55:8080");
    mHeaders.put("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    mHeaders.put("User-Agent","AndroidApp");
    mHeaders.put("Authorization","Basic Q2xpZW50NTkzMzppMjR3s2U="); // optional
}public final static InputStream receiveCurrentShipments(String stringUrlShipments)
{
    int status=0;
    String xmlstring= "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:ser=\"http://35.15.85.55:8080/ServiceTransfer\">\n" +
            "   <soap:Header/>\n" +
            "   <soap:Body>\n" +
            "      <ser:GetAllOrdersOfShipment>\n" +
            "         <ser:CodeOfBranch></ser:CodeOfBranch>\n" +
            "      </ser:GetAllOrdersOfShipment>\n" +
            "   </soap:Body>\n" +
            "</soap:Envelope>";
    StringBuffer chaine = new StringBuffer("");

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(stringUrlShipments);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", xmlstring.getBytes().length + "");
        connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "http://35.15.85.55:8080/ServiceTransfer/GetAllOrdersOfShipment");

        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mHeaders.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            connection.setRequestProperty(key,value);

        }

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);

        OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(xmlstring.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        outputStream.close();

        connection.connect();
        status = connection.getResponseCode();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        Log.i("HTTP Client", "HTTP status code : " + status);
    }

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return inputStream;
}
```

Comment: please help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573829/how-to-send-and-receive-soap-data-from-webservice-to-google-app-engine

Comment: two questions on this: 1. How is this called from main activity? 2. What should be the value of StringUrlShipment that's passed as a parameter?

Comment: on the above comment, ignore question #1.

Comment: From main activity you should use AsyncTask to call this code. Inside this AsyncTask class implement doInBackground to launch this code

Answer (score 2):

To call a SOAP web Service from android , try to use this client

DON'T FORGET TO ADD ksoap2-android.jar in your java build path

```java
public class WsClient {
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "somme";
    private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "somme";
    private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://example.ws";
    private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://192.168.1.2:8080/axis2/services/Calculatrice?wsdl";

    public String caclculerSomme() {

        String res = null;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
                OPERATION_NAME);
        request.addProperty("a", "5");
        request.addProperty("b", "2");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

        try {
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            String result = envelope.getResponse().toString();
            res = result;
            System.out.println("############# resull is :" + result);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("########### ERRER" + exception.getMessage());
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Wajdi hh how to compare response res from giver response result :- success ....."responce =1~Successfull"....  so how we compare that result from condition which are from server side ........

Answer (score 1):

Add Soap Libaray(`ksoap2-android-assembly-3.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`):

public static String  Fn_Confirm_CollectMoney_Approval(

```
        HashMap < String, String > str1,
        HashMap < String, String > str2,
        HashMap < String, String > str3) {

    Object response = null;
    String METHOD_NAME = "CollectMoney";
    String NAMESPACE = "http://xxx/yyy/xxx";
    String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
    String SOAP_ACTION = "";

    try {

        SoapObject RequestParent = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SoapObject Request1 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "req");

        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();

        Set mapSet1 = (Set) str1.entrySet();

        Iterator mapIterator1 = mapSet1.iterator();

        while (mapIterator1.hasNext()) {

            Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) mapIterator1.next();

            String keyValue = (String) mapEntry.getKey();

            String value = (String) mapEntry.getValue();

            pi = new PropertyInfo();

            pi.setNamespace("java:com.xxx");

            pi.setName(keyValue);

            pi.setValue(value);

            Request1.addProperty(pi);
        }

        mapSet1 = (Set) str3.entrySet();

        mapIterator1 = mapSet1.iterator();

        while (mapIterator1.hasNext()) {

            Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) mapIterator1.next();

            // getKey Method of HashMap access a key of map
            String keyValue = (String) mapEntry.getKey();

            // getValue method returns corresponding key's value
            String value = (String) mapEntry.getValue();

            pi = new PropertyInfo();

            pi.setNamespace("java:com.xxx");

            pi.setName(keyValue);

            pi.setValue(value);

            Request1.addProperty(pi);
        }

        SoapObject HeaderRequest = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "XXX");

        Set mapSet = (Set) str2.entrySet();

        Iterator mapIterator = mapSet.iterator();

        while (mapIterator.hasNext()) {

            Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) mapIterator.next();

            // getKey Method of HashMap access a key of map
            String keyValue = (String) mapEntry.getKey();

            // getValue method returns corresponding key's value
            String value = (String) mapEntry.getValue();

            pi = new PropertyInfo();

            pi.setNamespace("java:com.xxx");

            pi.setName(keyValue);

            pi.setValue(value);

            HeaderRequest.addProperty(pi);
        }

        Request1.addSoapObject(HeaderRequest);

        RequestParent.addSoapObject(Request1);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER10);

        soapEnvelope.dotNet = false;

        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(RequestParent);

        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 120000);

        transport.debug = true;

        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);

        response = (Object) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

        int cols = ((SoapObject) response).getPropertyCount();

        Object objectResponse = (Object) ((SoapObject) response)
                .getProperty("Resp");

        SoapObject subObject_Resp = (SoapObject) objectResponse;


        modelObject = new ResposeXmlModel();

        String MsgId = subObject_Resp.getProperty("MsgId").toString();


        modelObject.setMsgId(MsgId);

        String OrgId = subObject_Resp.getProperty("OrgId").toString();


        modelObject.setOrgId(OrgId);

        String ResCode = subObject_Resp.getProperty("ResCode").toString();


        modelObject.setResCode(ResCode);

        String ResDesc = subObject_Resp.getProperty("ResDesc").toString();


        modelObject.setResDesc(ResDesc);

        String TimeStamp = subObject_Resp.getProperty("TimeStamp")
                .toString();


        modelObject.setTimestamp(ResDesc);

        return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }

}
```