# Connecting to a webserver with android

Tags: android

I have to connect to a webserver from android and I have to access a webservice and a webpage from the webserver. Can anybody help me? Please give step by step process with some code snippets because I am new to android and I don't know anything in connecting to a webserver.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`HttpClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html):

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
// user reader to read & parse response 
reader.close();
```

Parsing the response obviously depends on the format (e.g. [SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android), [JSON](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given very much info (what kind of web page, XML/JSON/HTML/etc. ?).  But the basic principles of regular Java apply.  Using [URL](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html) and [InputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html):

```
URL url = new URL(...);
InputStream is = url.openStream();
```

And from there it depends what kind of data you're dealing with.

Comment: I have to access a ASP web page and a web service

Comment: What is the output format of the web page?  XML/JSON/HTML/...?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an additional library, here is a means for sending an "id" and "name" to a server:

```
    URL url = null;
    try {
        String registrationUrl = String.format("http://myserver/register?id=%s&name=%s", myId, URLEncoder.encode(myName,"UTF-8"));
        url = new URL(registrationUrl);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
        int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.d("MyApp", "Registration success");
        } else {
            Log.w("MyApp", "Registration failed for: " + registrationUrl);              
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You could just as easily send other data via this URI "GET" style, but if you need to send something more detailed a POST will be required.

Note: Originally posted to answer a similar question here: [How to connect android to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696190/how-to-connect-android-to-server/2701368)