# How to do Socket communication in android?

Tags: android, network-programming

I am having a task,considering one emulator as server and i have to access a web service from the client emulator.I think this is not possible in android,if anyone knows about it please send some code snippets to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android's [`java.net`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/package-summary.html) package is pretty much the same as Java's so you can use [`Socket`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html)s and [`ServerSocket`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html)s for TCP communication or a [`DatagramSocket`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) for UDP.

However, there is currently no support for *SOAP webservices* in the android SDK but you can use third party libraries or build your own. Have a look at the following questions:

- [How to call a net web service from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048310/how-to-call-a-net-web-service-from-android)
- [Regarding connecting to a webserver from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047698/regarding-connecting-to-a-webserver-from-android)

Comment: I find it interesting that both questions I linked to were asked by a user with the exact same name (but different user id). Did you re-register?