# Android app and Web server

Tags: android, webserver

I have an Android app, that needs to communicate with a webserver. However, I have no idea of how to do this. I do have a webserver., though I do not know how to use it(store/retrieve data). plz help me . any tips, advices will work for me. It is important. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Google does not help you?](https://www.google.com/)

Comment: You can use an HttpClient:

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
// user reader to read & parse response 
reader.close();

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047698/regarding-connecting-to-a-webserver-from-android so this is a duplicate? or do you need more info ? (and if so: what will it be?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See This is only for reference .in that i just passing two variable to web service and receive the response form server as per condition.

At the server side i have mange `PHP` to accept `POST` request and response in `JSON`.

So create simple php web service. for that you will get idea form `w3school` or any other web resource . Now you are abel to do this task.

Native code for android is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134019/http-post-method-passing-null-values-to-the-server/13134287#13134287).