# How to get data from My_SQL database to android

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-layout

In my application, i want to display data that is saved in MY_SQL on android application TextViews. How can i do it

my android application layout is:

```
     <LinearLayout 
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cus_name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cus_name_txta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/contact_no"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/contact_no_txta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

   </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView4"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/ticket_no"
             android:clickable="true"
             android:focusable="true"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/ticket_no_txta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

   <requestFocus />

    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/task_detail"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/task_detail_txt"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>



     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView6"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="@string/attend_by"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/attend_by_txta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

My java code is:

```
public static String attend_by_txt;

TextView cus_name_txt, contact_no_txt, ticket_no_txt;
TextView task_detail_txt;
 EditText attend_by_txtbx;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_task);


    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);


    cus_name_txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cus_name_txta);

           contact_no_txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contact_no_txta);

    task_detail_txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.task_detail_txt);
```

I want that when i click on customer_name, Contact_No, ticket_No, Task_detail. it display data that is saved in MY_SQL. Please guide me how can i retrieve data from database and display it in android. I'll be very thankful to you.

Comment: see this is my answer that will help you. let me know if you have any query .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640649/android-app-and-web-server/13640805#13640805

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on whether you want your database to be local or stored on a remote server.

**If it is local**, You'll have to convert your MYSQL db to a SQLite db since this the one that Android supports.

See here for instructions:

[Convert MySQL to SQlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890518/convert-mysql-to-sqlite)

Then you can access it using the native android methods. See db tutorial here:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

**If it is hosted on a remote server**, then you'll have to create REST API's (by writing server side code using a language like PHP, Ruby, Python etc) that your Android app can consume to obtain the data from the db.

There are other options that avoid REST API's as well. See:

[How to get from a MySql server to an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898823/get-data-to-android-app-from-mysql-server)

See here for a beginners tutorial on REST:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-beginners-introduction-to-http-and-rest/

Comment: Anup one thing i want to ask is that my android app is built on min sdk 7 it doesn't support sqlite database. how can i retrive data in it??

Comment: SQLite API's were added in SDK Version 1 itself. So all the versions support it. You shouldn't have a problem in this regard.