# Android SMS intercept without notification icon or WAP-PUSH messages

Tags: android, sms, notifications, broadcastreceiver

Is there a way to intercept an SMS with [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) as for example [here](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2008/12/android-api-sms-handling/) 
but without showing any notifications to the user and immediately deleting the message that contains for example some keyword

EDIT:

What I need is to have some communication between android phones, one to one, and I thought that sending SMS messages would solve the problem, but the SMS notification are not needed for that, maybe the WAP PUSH messages would better for that but I have no idea how to send them from android phone.
If someone has any idea that would help, please put it here :)

Comment: What's the name of your app?  I certainly question whether this is a wise design decision.  If I install your app and you delete SMS messages without notification only because you assume that I wouldn't ever use some magic keyword, I'll be pretty darn upset.

Comment: That actually doesn’t answer my question at all, but maybe I didn’t explain what I really want clear enough.

What I need is to have some communication between android phones, one to one, and I thought that sending SMS messages would solve the problem, but the SMS notification are not needed for that, I’m not going to remove uses messages, please answer to the question next time, no need to rant over the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some guys from the Ericsson lab presented their push solution during the droidcon this year (with some additional reasoning why push is good).

Here's the link to their site:
https://labs.ericsson.com/apis/mobile-java-push/blog/push-android-droidpush-droidcamp

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend PUSH or a web service to do the task your requesting.

WAP is a SMS message with a URL, it's goal is to allow users to download content from the web, kinda like a MMS message but for phones without MMS capability. Usually it's a premium message (Meaning the end user pays for these).

As for SMS, I don't think you can delete these from the phone without the knowledge of the user. Think legal on this. Would you want to receive and send SMS messages without your knowledge? SMS can also bill your phone so I'm thinking legally I would recommend avoiding this.

Another note if you're going to use SMS is that you would need a short code and a aggragator. Even if you have the short code and aggragator you still need the users permission to send reoccurring messages to their phone via application/phone.

I would recommend these links for reading:

1. [Android Push Notification](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4778a4e2ed9d49e1)
2. http://www.anddev.org/calling_a_web_service_from_android-t348.html
3. [Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could intercept Android SMS without notification icon.

Here is the solution: [Can we delete an SMS in Android before it reaches the inbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox/2566199#2566199)

Answer (score 1):

check out Xtify - similar to C2D for Froyo with the ability to push intents but, Xtify does a lot more and does it across Android, iPhone and Blackberry.

xtify uses an SDK for easy implementation and has a web console and web service to configure messages to one, some or all of your users.

you can create rules that determine when a message gets sent – you can even push notifications using location as the trigger as the SDK runs in the background and provides access to persistent location.

reach out with questions to business@xtify.com