# Can you intercept a MMS SMS message and extract the image on Android?

Tags: android, sms, mms

I want to basically intercept a text message that has an image attached, and save that somewhere automatically. Can this work on Android?

Comment: If by intercept you mean detect it and block it from other applications you cant do that

Comment: If by intercept you mean detect it and read its contents, then yes you can.
If by intercept you mean block it from other applications, then yes can do that too.

Comment: you can't attach a image to a SMS message, only MMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible.  You can set up a `BroadcastReceiver` to watch for the `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` and parse the message out of that.  There's plenty of examples on the web (and questions on StackOverflow).

As for preventing the user from seeing the original message, see also this answer:
[Can we delete an SMS in Android before it reaches the inbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox/2566199#2566199)