# How to prevent incoming SMS from reaching the inbox?

Tags: android, sms

I'm working on a simple app that receives, but not handles sms messages.  It checks each incoming sms for a specific keyphrase.  If the sms contains that keyphrase then it responds accordingly.  If the keyphrase doesn't exist, then my app does nothing. I have this much working.

I was wondering if there was a way to prevent the default sms app on the phone from receiving the text only if my app finds that keyphrase.

Thanks for the help
Andrew

Comment: Duplicate of [Can we delete an SMS in Android before it reaches the inbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox/2566199#2566199)

Answer (score 4):

in broadcast receiver set android:priority="100" and  in onRecieve()  this.abortBroadcast();
this will prevent from seeing the sms to other application .....even will not go into inbox