# How to prevent other apps from intercepting SMS?

Tags: android, sms

I'm building an SMS app that receives and sends SMS messages, with some extra features. I've noticed on some phones, when my app sends a message from device A to B, some other SMS apps in device B actually intercept the message, and hence my app in device B never gets the message.

Setting the other SMS app to not the default app, or changing the priority, often solves the problem. However, I'm assuming not all apps have these options that I can set.

What can I do in my app to increase its priority in receiving SMS messages, or prevent other apps from intercepting SMS messages?

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt there's much you can do. This should be something for the user to decide on.

Comment: All you can do is set the priority on your broadcast receiver, like [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330174/how-to-prevent-incoming-sms-from-reaching-the-inbox). However, there's no guarantee that other applications don't do the same. You should probably inform the users that if they're having difficulties with the app, the reason may be one of their third party apps handling SMS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Broadcast Receiver not processing SMS's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395925/broadcast-receiver-not-processing-smss)

Comment: Most of the SMS apps I've used require the user to _disable the default SMS app_ (as well as all others of course; this is under the assumption that the only two that exist on the phone are default and yours). It may be worth a try just notifying users of this.