# Disable notification of incoming/outgoing SMS in android

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to disable SMS received and send notification in status bar ??
What is the procedure to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

For a reliable solution, see this: [Can we delete an SMS in Android before it reaches the inbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox/2566199#2566199)

Answer (score 0):

Small hack, get the incoming message and number using a broadcastReceiver and put it somewhere(put it in the Log.d() to check) then this.abortBroadcast();

Comment: But it receives before intent called!!