# Deleting SMS Using BroadCastReceiver - Android

Tags: android

i have broadcast receiver class for receiving sms, but i dont know how to delete the received sms **before reaching to the inbox** as well as the notification

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     
        Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();     
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage messages =SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);        
        Log.i(TAG,  messages.getMessageBody());
}
```

Comment: Mind showing the code of your broadcast receiver?

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your intent filter you should set the priority higher than the systems SMS-application.

`<intent-filter android:priority="100" ...`

And then in your broadcast receiver you call `abortBroadcast()`

```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     //... 
     abortBroadcast();
   }
```

Comment: Won't this stop ALL broadcasts? he should have if intent.action().equals("WhateverTheActionIsCalled")

Comment: Arun: Do you have a custom SMS-application installed? If that application have higher priority than your intent filter then they will recieve it first. try increasing the priority. Also if you don't return from `onRecieve()` quickly it could continue to the next broadcast reciever.

Comment: Android priority not working for me here is the code iam using in mani fest file.. <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name=
                    "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"  />
            </intent-filter> 
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000"> 
          
   </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>

Comment: is any permission required to use abortBroadcast();??

Comment: @Sando: Try using android:priority="9999"

Answer (score 1):

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver"
         android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"> 
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" > 
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and in receiver

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     //... 
     abortBroadcast();
   }
```

This will work fine.