# Abort sms broadcast and/or delete received sms from inbox

Tags: java, android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to write sms encryption tool. People using this tool will be able to chat without internet via sms and stay encrypted.
The only thing I need is how to stop sms from particular number from getting into inbox folder, or delete sms notification and then delete sms from inbox.

I googled a lot, but 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3875736/705297
this is not working. Broadcast is working, I see the log message that broadcastreceiver is launched, but it doesn't abort broadcast.

Also I found lots of messages that it is impossible. So is it possible and how I can do that? I am using android 2.1 and higher. 
Thanks

Code (just tries to cancel all sms for testing purposes):
Broadcast receiver:

```
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
      abortBroadcast(); }
```

Part of manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

 <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: it should work. maybe your priority is not high enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also need to have BROADCAST_SMS permission. That was my problem. Here is the working part of manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
....
 <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
          <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Permission is only granted to system apps :: BROADCAST_SMS ?