# How to know in my own application, when user captured a picture with default camera application?

Tags: android, gps, camera, notifications, image

Is it possible to get notified about picture being captured in Android OS? I want to create my own app, which will add GPS coordinates if picture was taken so fast, that GPS was not yet ready at the capture moment.

I would go to the picture file and fix this by adding GPS coordinates when it would be ready.

Any tips around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to refer to [Android: BroadcastReceiver intent to Detect Camera Photo Taken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389427/android-broadcastreceiver-intent-to-detect-camera-photo-taken) as this appears to be a duplicate.

In particular it seems you need to have a ContentObserver for the Media directory, this isn't a perfect solution (no guarantee of content type, etc), but I can't seem to find any reference to a broadcasted intent for this particular event.