# Detect pic taken in Android using Tasker app

Tags: android

I am trying to detect when a picture is taken, as a trigger (to also make a picture of the photographer)

Tasker has a trigger for the Hardware Camera button, but my phone (Galaxy Nexus) has only software buttons.

Any ideas? I was thinking of using the trigger Action -> File modified, and then point to a file that Android edits when making a picture (like a log file, or a list of pictures).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This says no: [Android: BroadcastReceiver intent to Detect Camera Photo Taken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389427/android-broadcastreceiver-intent-to-detect-camera-photo-taken)

And here's a workaround:

[broadcast receiver won't receive camera event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571461/broadcast-receiver-wont-receive-camera-event)

use a file observer, instead of a `BroadcastReciever`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I found was a bit of a workaround. It doesn't detect a picture being taken as such but rather I put a detection on when the camera app exits. This may not work for all purposes but I just wanted to kick of a folder sync to backup my pics to the cloud. In this case leaving the camera app works a treat!