# Detecting an image capture

Tags: android

I need to detect an image capture by the native android app. Is there any way to do this?
Some questions I have looked into in this respect are:-
[Android: BroadcastReceiver intent to Detect Camera Photo Taken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389427/android-broadcastreceiver-intent-to-detect-camera-photo-taken)

Answer (score 0):

There is no broadcast action available to filter the image capture action being performed.

Check in the link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON, only "android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" is available to detect the "camera button" pressed.

Comment: Yeah I get that,Is there any work around? Putting a content observer in the media store would trigger for all the images being added right?
Suppose If I get an image via blue tooth then that also will be taken into account I suppose?

Comment: Exactly, the content observer will be interrupted when image is downloaded from bluetooth, or from internet or from other applications like what's app too.
Provide me the application details you are building, so i can help you with some idea, if i can.