# Android app that opens inbox SMS

Tags: android, sms, receiver

I am using an SMS manager in my app, so when a button is clicked, an SMS is sent,

```
btnPaket.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()


    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String phoneNo = "0977";
            String message = "stanje";

            sendSMS(phoneNo, message);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Zahtjev za provjeru stanja paketa je poslan, odgovor ocekuj uskoro!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

So when I click on the button, the SMS is sent, and I get an automated response with the state of my SMS, and Internet packets. Is there any way such that a received SMS is automatically opened and shown to the user, without leaving the application, and going to the inbox, or the notifications bar?

Comment: For intercepting incoming SMSes, see [this answer to "Sending and receiving SMSes without a native messaging application"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770853/sending-and-receiving-smses-without-a-native-messaging-application/4771341#4771341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Android allows you to directly open/read text messages (for extremely obvious reasons...), however, you might be able to just launch the SMS inbox from your application.

Reference [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) to how to launch activities.

**EDIT:**
[This](http://www.anddev.org/open_sms_activity-t6375.html) person apparently found out how to open the sms inbox, check his second post.

Comment: Ok, thanks for reply. If i can directly open message, can i show message body in toast ??