# disable the notification of sms in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we delete an SMS in Android before it reaches the inbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox)

i am working on android sms app and i just want to disable the sms notification for particular messages.
I had tried shared preference to uncheck the sms notification  but it didn't work;after that i tried to update  the message status using broadcast receiver onreceive method but then also notification appers....can someone suggest me how to disable the sms notificatioin of native android sms app using shared preference or any other way

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6):

You could intercept the SMS in a `BroadcastReceiver`, abort the broadcast to prevent any SMS apps from seeing it, then manually insert the SMS into the SMS `ContentProvider`.

But then that's terrible, fragile, uses non-public APIs and will possibly break third-party SMS applications.

So basically, no you can't do this properly.

Comment: i had already used onreceive method() of brodcast receiver class but thing is that is it possible to abort the broadcast receiver....do u suggest me any method do doing that.....

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, follow the link:
[Can we delete an SMS in Android before it reaches the inbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox/2566199#2566199)
If you need more information, just let me know, I'll post some example code.

Comment: +Benjamin: Can you share example code for me ? I am also looking for the best way for this case ....Thanks in advance :)