# Stoping other services like receving call and media player when my application opens?

Tags: android

When i open my application , i should not receive any phone call or sms i should stop the media player also. can any one tel me is there any API is available to disable and enable them  again once after my application ends.please help me..

Thanks 
RAM

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to block the phone call as referring to [this article](http://blog.wangling.me/2009/08/why-it-is-impossible-to-intercept-incoming-calls-on-android/).
For intercepting coming sms, you may be interested in [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034249/disable-the-notification-of-sms-in-android). Apparently there is a way to do that, but not a clean one.