# Changing text of Android sms

Tags: android, sms

I want to create a censorship app for Android. Idea is that service would "listen" for "SMS_RECIVED" broadcast, and when new sms arrives, it would change some parts of it before system sms app receive it. How can i change text of incoming sms message? Is there any example?

**EDIT:** What do you think about this: After receiving sms broadcast, my app would search SMS INBOX database for unread messages and then change sms text directly in database. Does it sound better?

Comment: I am not sure but I think that we cannot change sms as they are only readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [can intercept the message and cancel it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox/2566199#2566199) based on a particular filter, but you won't be able to change the text body.

The text body is stored in the class [com.android.internal.telephony.SmsMessageBase](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/telephony/SmsMessage.java/), so you do not have direct access to it through the public API. You might get access to it [through reflection](https://web.archive.org/web/20210117124429/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2010/07/access-internal-classes-in-android.html).