# SMS Broadcast Receiver doesn't get the textmessage

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

**What I've done**

---

Hello Guys, I'm creating at the moment a SMS Broadcast Receiver, i just builded one up with this tutorial: [Broadcasttutorial](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android). After I did the code, I updated my Manifest. After that I sent sms from my other Phone to my Phone, but It didn't work. I didn't get any output.

**Question**

---

What do I need to change, that I can receive those SMS. Please gimme a detailed anwser that I can learn it, a good tutorial would also be great!

**Code**

---

SMSBroadcastReceiver (is in package .services)

```
package de.retowaelchli.filterit.services;

import de.retowaelchli.filterit.R;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SmileySmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Log.d("SmileySmsReceiver", "Yes it calls the onReceive");
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";        
            }
            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }                         
    }
}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="de.retowaelchli.filterit"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <!--  User Permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>  

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:debuggable="true"
                 android:screenOrientation="sensor"
                 android:theme="@style/FilterIt.Theme"> 

        <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

     <!-- Receiver -->
        <receiver android:name="de.retowaelchli.filterit.services.SmileySmsReceiver" android:enabled="true"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>     



        <!--  Startseite -->
        <activity android:name=".StartseiteActivity"></activity>

        <!-- Von Startseite ausgehende Activitys -->   
        <activity android:name=".SmileyActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ADeleteActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".StatsActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".HelpMenuActivity"></activity>


        <!-- Von Stats ausgehende Activitys -->
        <activity android:name=".stats.ADFilterStats"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".stats.SFilterStats"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".stats.CreatedADFilters"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".stats.CreatedSFilters"></activity>

        <!-- Von ADeleteActivity ausgehende Activitys -->
        <activity android:name=".ADFilterConfigActivity"></activity>

        <!--  Von SmileyActivity ausgehende Activitys -->
        <activity android:name=".SFilterConfigActivity"></activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />` outside of the `<application>` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="de.retowaelchli.filterit"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:debuggable="true"
                 android:screenOrientation="sensor"
                 android:theme="@style/FilterIt.Theme"> 

    <!-- Receiver -->
        <receiver android:name="de.retowaelchli.filterit.services.SmileySMSBroadcastReceiver"> 
            <intent-filter android:priority="999"> 
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>
       …
       …
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**UPDATE**

Turned out that @safari uses "Handcent SMS" application on his phone which intercepts incoming SMS (this is possible because `SMS_RECEIVED` is an ordered broadcast and can be canceled by high priority broadcast receivers, refer [to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox/2566199#2566199) for details).
To bypass this issue one would need to install broadcast receiver with higher priority than "Handcent SMS". @safari used the highest priority allowed for applications in Android: **999**, and it worked for him.
To specify priority of broadcast receiver add `android:priority` attribute to corresponding `<intent-filter>` item:

```
<receiver android:name="YourSmsBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999"> 
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: i did that, but it didn't work i still don't get the toastmessage with the message in it, whats wrong :(?

Comment: in logcat I don't have any output,i also made some Log.v, into the code but I also don't see those.

Comment: @safari use the full class name of the broadcast receiver: `<receiver android:name="de.retowaelchli.filterit.services.SmileySMSBroadcastReceiver">` (see my updated answer)

Comment: i tried this, i still don't see anything on my logcat about my receiver

Comment: @safari Is your broadcast `onReceive` method being called? Have you tried to put `Log.d` at the very beginning of `onReceive` method? Also did you try [sample project](http://mobiforge.com/sites/mobiforge.com/files/SMSMessaging.zip) provided in the tutorial you refer to?

Comment: yes I did, but I don't get log.d output but i see nothing in logcat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4506/discussion-between-idolon-and-safari)

Comment: Apps like Hancent sms and go sms hacked a way to be at the top of the priority list.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<pdus.length; i++)
```

instead of msgs.length, pdus contains the real sms messages.

Comment: That's how I implemented my SMS Receiver, if you want I can post my implementation tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

gauglerb pointed me in the right direction here with his comment for the accepted answer and I think I should share my findings.

Handcent has indeed been a bad boy and are not letting any other apps receive messages when it is installed.

Fortunately there is an easy solution if you don't want to uninstall Handcent:
In the Application settings of Handcent there is an option to make Handcent the default Messaging application. If this is disabled, messages can come through to other receivers.

Answer (score 0):

Give permission in `MainActivity` in `onCreate` method. It will work.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS}, 10);

}
```