# Get recipient's number from an incoming SMS

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

Is possible to get the recipient of a text message with a `BroadcastReceiver`?

If so, how?

Comment: you mean the number of the person who sends the sms ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887256/sms-broadcast-receiver-doesnt-get-the-textmessage?rq=1

Comment: @YeLinAung:
No, the number of the person who receives the sms (In other words: my phone number).

Comment: @Sunny - what does that question have to do with this one?

Comment: I have the same question... It's like there's 5 similar questions on stackoverflow, but none of them are solved.

Comment: have you found the solution for this?