# Broadcast receiver not getting called on SMS_RECEIVED

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am new to Android programming and currently learning it for an app. I am trying to intercept the SMSs that are received and extract information from them. This may be a duplicate question but I need help specific to my problem. My broadcast receiver is not getting called.I have declared the receiver in the Manifestfile and created a receiver class that extends to BroadcastReceiver Where am I going wrong.

ManifestFile:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.receivingsms.SMSReceiver"> 
<intent-filter> 
            <action android:name=
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

SMSReceiver.java:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";            
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";        
        }
        //---display the new SMS message---
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }           
}
```

Comment: Did you add correct permission in AndroidManifest? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>

Comment: Yes UserPermission:                                              <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
    </uses-permission>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887256/sms-broadcast-receiver-doesnt-get-the-textmessage?rq=1 might be a case of adding android:priority="999" in <intent-filter> block, as detailed in the post.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm marking as duplicate for future reference.