# how to transefer data between devices using client-server-server-client though wifi

Tags: android, sockets, client-server, wifi

I'm developing an android application use WiFi network to send and receive data between users i'm trying to implement something like client-server-server-client, for example user A send data to user B and user B can reply to user A and sends files or text.
How to do something like this? Anything help please.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the code you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send data from one android device to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797613/how-to-send-data-from-one-android-device-to-another)