# Implementation of data flow between devices?

Tags: android, ios, tcp, bluetooth, data-transfer

A similar question was asked [**`How to send data from one android device to another?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797613/how-to-send-data-from-one-android-device-to-another)

However their scope of data pass is between android devices.

And so to extend that question, I wanted to know ways of connecting two completely separate devices like ECG device to apps (Android or IOS).

For example, [**`AliveCor`**](https://www.alivecor.com/?gclid=CjwKCAjwssvPBRBBEiwASFoVdyGW9xSDYuWHHfFKNkMVbd4PU-4eqmkQLYhTcPK06eaZtBSBRmLkvxoC2y4QAvD_BwE) allows to send reading of external device to their mobile app.

So what ways do we have apart from Bluetooth or TCP/IP?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is NFC(Near field communication). You can transmit data when phone(with NFC) is near to another device (with NFC). Also,

> For example, AliveCor allows to send reading of external device to their mobile app.

this app use NFC for transmitting data.

From permissions ( google play AliveCor Kardia app)

[image]

Also read the information about this system on https://www.alivecor.com/faq/

https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=H-JRAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA41&ots=EV9Qy61sjY&dq=nfc%20data%20transfer%20ECG&hl=uk&pg=PA41#v=onepage&q=nfc%20data%20transfer%20ECG&f=false

Comment: Not an option if need to support iPhone. NFC still very limited on iPhone (in many regards, but mainly it is limited to iOS 11 and iPhone 7 & 8 & X only).

Comment: I agree with @RaimundasSakalauskas This is something out of scope currently.

Comment: Yes, but AliveCor using NFC. You can try to use it, or find information about it.

Comment: Are you sure about them using NFC? All of their screenshots show BT devices connected, their app is supporting iOS 9, whereas NFC was only made available in iOS starting iOS 11 (apart from apple pay). They might use NFC to ease the pairing / activation where it's available, but not to transfer data (at least not on iOS).

Answer (score 0):

You have essentially listed all reasonable means that are used nowadays. You can either transfer data via bluetooth, using your own/3rd party hosted webservices like firebase or direct tcp/ip connection. TCP/IP probably being the hardest, bluetooth being 2nd hardest and webservice being the easiest but yet requiring both devices to be online. The implementation is however totally your responsibility (with web you would either add user registration and sync user data to all signed in devices, or if sync is one time thing, you could upload data to your server, issue a expiring token, which if entered in other device allow it to download that data).

Comment: +1 for mentioning firebase as a server for data transmission. So in this instance bluetooth would be preferred as you'd want ECG device close to your self along with your phone to send reading from ECG device to your phone.

Comment: It depends. I personally hate bluetooth. My magic mouse tracks erratically with 2016 macbook pro (to the point where i switched to logitech g403 as my office mouse), bluetooth headphones sometimes introduce artefacts or get stuck (especially on the same macbook pro lol). If you have 3 devices paired to one source and all of them are nearby, most likely host will pair with the wrong device (2/3 chance :)). Pairing process is painful, distance is limited. If possible I would always chose wifi over bluetooth. If you only pair ECG with one phone - then BT probably will require less maintenance.