# android Notifications works on emulator but not on phone

Tags: android

I am writing an application that executes notifications upon receiving sms messages.  It works fine in the emulator but does not work on my phone.  I tried debugging the app but there are no errors in the logs.  Could it be that another sms app is hogging the notification and my app is not allowed to execute a notification?

The notification is suppose to trigger an mp3 that I have packaged in /raw/.  The mp3 are 1 or 2 sec long.

cheers,
Jay

Comment: Can you post some code to go along with this?

Comment: Here is my BroadcastReceiver class :

Comment: I take it my question is to broad or too specific?  Should I include more information?

Comment: Ok - figure out what was wrong but not sure why.  I had "Go SMS" app on my Android that was not allowing my app to receive the sms notification.  I uninstalled the app and now it works.  My question is how can an app take over all Broadcasted messages?  How can I work around that in my app - or give that option in my app?

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox) for a discussion about the way sms broadcasts are sent and how you can prioritize your app.