# Receive SMS via My application in android

Tags: java, android, sms

I am developing an android application that would let people send and receive SMS to a unique number via my application. I can send SMS but it is appearing in INBOX message box!

I want it to appear in my application

I googled and find this but I do not want it to appear in Toast message, I want it like in What's app in android and how to save all the SMS from this number?

this is the code:

```
package net.learn2develop.SMSMessaging;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage; 
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
   {
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";            
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";        
        }
        //---display the new SMS message---
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }                         
 } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per: [Can we delete an SMS in Android before it reaches the inbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox)

> Incoming SMS message broadcasts
>   (android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED) are delivered as an
>   "[ordered broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)" — meaning that you can tell the system which
>   components should receive the broadcast first.
>
> If you define an android:priority attribute on your SMS-listening
>   , you will then receive the notification before the
>   native SMS application.
>
> At this point, you can [cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast%28%29) the broadcast, preventing it from
>   being propagated to other apps.

Comment: so i  should write `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED)` in my manifest then it will appear in my app before the native inbox?

Comment: or there is something else i should do?

Comment: also how can i save the all sms from this number? when i put my code it is just receive one SMS then when i receive another sms the first one is deleted

Comment: Follow this example: http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, you should have something that looks like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Note **android:priority="999"**.

In your `onReceive()` method, **the first line** should be `abortBroadcast();`. Timing does matter and you will get bundle from the intent.