# How to programatically disable the Android Status Bar?

Tags: android, statusbar, notificationmanager

I am trying to make an SMS app in android. There are some messages which contents I want to keep hidden but as soon as I receive a message, android `stausbar` shows the contents of the message. How can I disable this programatically in my application?

Comment: Did you mean the Notification Bar?

Comment: yeah the bar just above the `ActionBar`...

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this question

[Can we delete an SMS in Android before it reaches the inbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox/2566199#2566199)

It shows you how to use a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for SMS notifications and cancel them reaching other applications. This will allow your SMS app to display whatever notifications you wish, or don't.

Comment: after setting the priority of `IntentFilter`, how can I just disable the `NotificationBar` not to show any message content then hiding it completely.

Comment: because I dont want to make other messaging app not to receive the intent so I am not cancelling the broadcast.Is it even possible? because I cannot make other apps not to show sms contents in `notificationbar`...