# Android stop notification in status bar while receiving message

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-notification-bar

I'm developing an application , and want to check every SMS  messages content for a specific text , and do some actions the delete the SMS , and not let user notify if the message contained that text , else I will recreate a notification and notify user ,
I am using `BroadcatReceiver` , and I can read the message the moment it arrives , but cant stop the notification in notification bar , I've searched but couldn't get satisfactory answer, any help would be appreciated

that is my `bradcasrReceiver` class

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Detected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

}
```

Comment: no, you can't stop system notification. check truecaller application.

Comment: why???? but Tango is doing something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend it to watch this :

[Can we delete an SMS in Android before it reaches the inbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox/2566199#2566199)

but becareful about android:priority ,

As of Android 1.6, incoming SMS message broadcasts (android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED) are delivered as an "ordered broadcast" — meaning that you can tell the system which components should receive the broadcast first.

If you define an android:priority attribute on your SMS-listening , you will then receive the notification before the native SMS application.