# How to block/unblock all incoming/outgoing calls/text messages in android?

Tags: android, message, blocking, phone-call

I am developing an android application for teenagers, they **can not do/receive** any **incoming/outgoing calls/text messages** during driving and also they can change status either he/she is driving or not. In my application I want to handle both situations **Block/Unblock incoming/outgoing calls/text messages**. If you have any idea related to this question than please share with me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 8 Hours R&D I found my Own Solution for my above question:

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.deactivateimservicedemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <!-- For Incoming Text messages -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.deactivateimservicedemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.deactivateimservicedemo.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnActivate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Activate" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDeactivate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Deactivate" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.deactivateimservicedemo;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button btnActivate, btnDeactivate;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    private IntentFilter filter;
    private boolean isReceiverRegistered;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnActivate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActivate);
        btnActivate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                /*Register Receiver*/
                registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
                isReceiverRegistered = true;
            }
        });

        btnDeactivate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDeactivate);
        btnDeactivate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*UnRegister Receiver*/
                if(isReceiverRegistered){
                    Log.i("Receiver is", "Register");
                    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
                }else {
                    Log.i("Receiver is", "Not Register");
                }
            }
        });

        filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
        filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");

        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                Log.i("Intent Action", action);
                if(intent!=null){
                    if(action.equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")){
                        try {
                            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context
                                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                            Class<?> c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
                            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                            m.setAccessible(true);
                            com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m
                                    .invoke(tm);
                            telephonyService.endCall();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
                        }
                    }else if(action.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
                        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                        if (extras != null) {
                            abortBroadcast();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        btnDeactivate.performClick();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**That's IT.**

Comment: what is `abortBroadcast();` , actually how you block incoming sms? thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

Use the [new Activity API](http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html) to detect when user is in driving mode.

To block incoming call you will have to listen for **TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING**
events and kill the incoming call. See [code example here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/333253/Block-Incoming-calls-in-android-without-single-rin)

I'm not sure what you mean by blocking incoming SMS. Do you want to delete arriving
SMSs while user is driving (bad idea)? If so - read [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox/2566199#2566199). This tecqnique 
should work for at least Android < 4.4. Remember to assign highest priority possibly 
to your SMS receiver.

Comment: Does the Activity Recognition API only uses Sensors like accelerometer, gyro etc or it also use Location information (GPS/Network)?

Comment: Got no hard data here. My guess is that is does that so it can calculate your speed. Driving has a different velocity than standing e.g.

Comment: Yes can say that the API is using `Accelerometer` to detect change in x, y direction values and on the basis of some fixed value indicator determing activity!

Answer (score 0):

There are several attempts.  Use GooglePlayServices Drive Api
    https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/drive.html

Then you can check the speed. If this is higher then 6km/h you may want to register an telephony and SMS BroadcastReceiver.

With the Receivers you can handle the incoming stuff.
This is how it should be done.

Another attempt is checking GPS Position with a PositionChance of example 10 metres, calculate the time between the location-jumps and if it's less then 2sec for 10 metres you can enable this too, using an AlarmManager which blocks the stuff for at least 30 minutes.

Another attempts is checking the CellIDs (position) and validating how often it is changed to a new CellID (position).

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40524 Is a good example how to get the Location using CellIDs

Comment: thanks for co-operate with me, exactly I need sample code for this, just want to handle block/unblock calls and messaging.