# How to boot android phone programmatically?

Tags: android, sms, reset

I want to reboot targeted phone by SMS.  Is it possible?  How can we implement this?

Comment: I hope not, that would be really scary :-)

Comment: Well, IF the phone had an app waiting for a specific SMS and after its arrival it would reboot itself it might be possible. But thats just a guess.

Comment: Does the number of '?' quantify the difficulty level of the questions?

Comment: Why is this tagged "Java ME" ?

Answer (score 7):

According to [this Android Developers thread on Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5a97467ef5b4bf47/a1fe9379d4f5e30f), third party applications don't have permission to reboot the device.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has two core parts. Can you reboot the phone programatically? Can you write a program to intercept incoming SMS? If you answered YES to both of your question, it is possible to do this.

I am not a Android developer but i think this should be quite possible.

take a look @ [Android SMS intercept without notification icon or WAP-PUSH messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732537/android-sms-intercept-without-notification-icon-or-wap-push-messages) and http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

I think BroadcastReceiver is the one you are looking for.

I have no idea whether you can programatically reset the android phone using java... Someone else might answer you about that

EDIT: I guess according to the link Bill has posted, 3rd party applications are not permitted to do a reset

Comment: K.. We can't reboot but can we switch off android phone programmatically ??

Comment: @Kanika: I honestly do not know whether it is possible as I am not an Android developer :(

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by having an app waiting for a specific text, then only on a rooted phone.

Ranhiru's link tells you how to get the text without it giving a text notification. If your phone isn't rooted, then programs don't have access to functions like that. If it's rooted, I can't say exactly how to do it, I haven't tried yet, but have a look for the source of apps like quickboot, a lot of them have it all publically available on code.google.com

Comment: k..
whatever i came to from google search is we can't reboot our phone programmatically until it is rooted.

Comment: But can anyone please explain is it possible to switch off our phone programmatically instead of reboot ?

Please reply fast.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, it IS possible to intercept SMS messages on a stock Android phone - I've written a little app which pops up a Toast when I get a text rather than having to go in to the messages app.

It's NOT possible to perform a normal shutdown/reboot/??? without rooting the phone or being Google (at least, convinving the phone you're Google) but that would be a violation of the developer agreement.

In fact, you will find huge barriers in your way if you try to do anything to the OS or any other app - Which is usually a good thing