# Shutdown menu by code

Tags: android, menu, shutdown, power-off

Is there a way to make the "Phone Options" menu ( the one that is showed when you long press the power button with power off / airplane mode ... ) show by code without having to root the phone ?
The idea is just to show it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `PowerDialog` [source](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#Un7TjJoIwb4/phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PowerDialog.java&type=cs), as it shows you how it is implemented and what layouts have been used. I can't see why you couldn't create a widget or an app that has the same functions without rooting.

Comment: I'll take a look at it. That's what I've been trying to figure out.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Same question was asked here:
[How to call power off,reboot dialog from application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791790/how-to-call-power-off-reboot-dialog-from-application)

Answer in short: Can't be done.

Alternatively, use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nappent.apps&hl=de
Require root though.

PS: I am answering this old question because it was the first hit I found.