# Is it possible to add additional menu options in android to the dialog that's triggered by long clicking the power button?

Tags: android

When long clicking the power button, Android bring up a dialog with one option called "Power off". Is there a way to add a second option to that dialog?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957104/how-can-i-open-power-off-dialog-on-android

Comment: Second link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791790/how-to-call-power-off-reboot-dialog-from-application

Answer (score 0):

Of course not，if you can do this，the user will be confuse when they want to do the Power off option.In fact,sometimes long clicking the power button is using for force reboot when the Android system didn't respond