# Retrieve data from a web server for android application

Tags: android, webserver

I am developing an application that needs to retrieve some data from a web server. But I have no idea how can this be possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android

Comment: Wow, where to start? Do you have a phone? which phone do you have? Do you have experience programming in Java? Have you looked at the Android SDK? Are you having problems with your server? What data are you trying to work with? Give us *something* to answer.

Comment: I have some experience in Java programming. I have started the app, I even built the UI. I have a web server with PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Just search this site; there are many similar Android + HTTP questions already asked and answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create what is called a **web service**. This **web service** acts as a web page that can be read easily by machines. This page will let your program make HTTP posts and gets  (Just like a web browser) in order to request and receive information. You can look at this page for the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to see an example of how it works.

For the protocol that you use to communicate, you have many options. Among the most popular are [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Example).

To create the web service itself you have a multitude of options. It seems to be Java Servlet s and PHP are popular, but there are many others (ASP, Perl, Python ...).