# passing parameter

Tags: android

How to pass parameter value to webservice in android

Answer (score 0):

A webservice request is still a basic POST method, and some accept GET.

Open the WSDL (if its a MS service, e.g. ends with .asmx) and this will show examples of the request packet...

http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit

====================================

```
HTTP POST

The following is a sample HTTP POST request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

POST /webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit HTTP/1.1
Host: www.w3schools.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

Celsius=string
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">string</string>
```

=================================

HEADER
    POST /webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.w3schools.com
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Content-Length: length

BODY
    string

Therefore the body is "string=32"

HttpClient will do...

Also see : - 
[Android, sending XML via HTTP POST (SOAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559948/android-sending-xml-via-http-post-soap)

You could also try KSOAP, however you !could! be embarking on a world of pain, I never really made friends with it....

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to construct the entire soap packet and post that. I prefer that way, as if the provider removes the POST verb, your still ok.

So builder the soap packet (from the asmx example in the link above) and post that.

Fiddler will also help you here.