# How to POST xml file using http request in Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to POST the following xml to a server url, but i don't know how to go about it. GET requests are easy enough, but I'm having a problem with POST requests.

```
<? xml version=1.0>
<Request>
<Elemtnt>
<data id="1">E1203</data>
<data id="2">E1204</data>
</Element>
</Request>
```

Comment: For one, your XML is broken. `<Elemtnt>` and `</Request`.

Comment: Now read my question It is edited..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recreate a string like this: 
`String myXML = "<?xml version=1.0> <Request> <Elemtnt> <data id=\"1\">E1203</data> <data id=\"2\">E1204</data></Element></Request>";`

and use the same string in my previous answer: [How to attach XML file in message body of HTTP post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737610/how-to-attach-xml-file-in-message-body-of-http-post-request/7738506#7738506)

Answer (score 3):

This question has been answered many times on Stackoverflow.

Here:
[Android, sending XML via HTTP POST (SOAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559948/android-sending-xml-via-http-post-soap)

and here:
[Android, send and receive XML via HTTP POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013373/android-send-and-receive-xml-via-http-post-method)

and here:
[Send xml files in android with http post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582830/send-xml-files-in-android-with-http-post)

If you already do it this way, then post some of your code.