# sending SOAP request

Tags: android, soap, http-post

In my application I want to send a SOAP request to some url, the SOAP request to be sent is as below

```
POST /TelLink/WrenchENTService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://WrenchGlobal/GetToDoList"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<GetToDoList xmlns="http://WrenchGlobal/">
    <viPeriod>int</viPeriod>
    <vsUserID>string</vsUserID>
  </GetToDoList>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

In the above code, I will have to replace "int" and "string" with actual values and it will invoke GetToDoList on the server. My problem is, I dont know how to send this request to the server? (using httppost) Could anyone help me out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android, sending XML via HTTP POST (SOAP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559948/android-sending-xml-via-http-post-soap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int viPeriod;
String vsUserID;
String NAMESPACE = "http://WrenchGlobal/";
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://WrenchGlobal/GetToDoList";
String METHOD_NAME = "GetToDoList";

String result = null;
Object resultRequestSOAP = null;

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

request.addProperty("viPeriod", viPeriod);
request.addProperty("vsUserID", vsUserID);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

try {
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    String requestDumpString = androidHttpTransport.requestDump;
    System.out.println("requestDump : " + requestDumpString);

    resultRequestSOAP = envelope.getResponse(); // Output received
    result = resultRequestSOAP.toString(); // Result string

    System.out.println("OUTPUT : " + result);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: thank you. What is that NAMESPACE in the above code..? Do i have it in the SOAP request above...? Dont i need to create all that SOAP request(in xml)....?

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the NAMESPACE (from the web service method you have provided) and the requestDump. The request is being send in the required xml format, which could be understood from the requestDump.

Comment: In the above edited code, what is SoapEnvelope.VER11 ? Is it something that needs explicite care, like initialization or something...? In line, "androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);" what should i use as SOAP_ACTION..?

Comment: The version parameter must be set to one of VER10, VER11 or VER12. You may refer the following link to know more about the SoapEnvelope class: http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/doc/api/org/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope.html

Comment: What all to import in my application in order to use ksoap2 ? I have added ksoap2 library to my application already. When i used your code, its giving messages saying "can not be resolved".

Comment: "Can not be resolved". Do you mean the code doesn't compile? If so try by adding the ksoap in class path.

Answer (score 0):

[IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) [HttpPost](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) are probably what you want. There are plenty of snippets available on Google; [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)'s just one of them.

Comment: Thank you. But i did not understand where actually i have to embed the above soap request into httppost object? How actually i can place the soap request in httppost object?

Comment: In that case, your best bet is probably a library. There's a pretty well-rounded discussion of SOAP and Android here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-with-android

Comment: I think i could use the answer for this stack overfolw question. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559948/android-sending-xml-via-http-post-soap). Am i right?

Comment: I see no reason why not. I'm not familiar enough with SOAP to help beyond the universal HTTP stuff for Android, however.

Comment: This is more than enough. Thanks uh...! :)