# Size limit of a String while posting to server

Tags: android, string, http

I am posting a string to server. If string size is up to 6000KB then its posted successfully. But when size exceeded more than this its showing response -1.

I have tried method of posting:  **syn_data1** is string . records fetch from data base and then appending to A string builder and finally i create synData1 string from String builder

```
URL url = new URL(syn_data1);
URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection)urlc;
huc.setRequestMethod("POST");
huc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
huc.connect();
int response = huc.getResponseCode();
```

I do care about each special character and remove.But I did not get success

Comment: Please don't use tabs when posting code on Stack Overflow. Simply indent your code by four spaces. It would also help if you'd say *exactly* what you mean by "I did not get success" - what *exactly* happened? Which string is long - one of the name/value pairs, or the URL?

Comment: Thnx for editing but i have tried both way using namevaluepair and appending to url.but im getting responce -1

Comment: It's unclear what that really means... have you tried using Wireshark to see what's happening at the network level? (I assume this happens on the emulator as well as a real device.)

Comment: its happening on both real device and emulator

Comment: In that case you should be able to see what's happening with Wireshark fairly clearly.

Comment: Did you try searching for it before asking?

Comment: Yes i search a lot but i didnot hear this word

Comment: @JonSkeet :have a look now .and i start reading about wireshark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, the URI in an HTTP request can be of any length, but the practical limit is on the order of 2k.  Please [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/417142/725163) for more info on that.

I am assuming the length is coming from the query string parameters (those `name=value` pairs that come after the `?`).  You should be putting these in the `POST` data, leaving the `path` part of the URI only.  Of course, the server will have to be looking for those parameters in the `POST` data as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response one upvote for your help.Read my below comment

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing the NameValue pairs properly . This is one successful way which i use .

```
 List<NameValuePair> loginParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
 loginParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ColumnName In DB",YourString));
```

then you do

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(loginParams));
```

and proceed to execute

Comment: @E.dan and @ Saiesh: i am passing namevalue properly but my problem is that im changing my string into json format and now second code in my question telling invalid parameter

Comment: [Try something like this example for XML - should be pretty similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559948/android-sending-xml-via-http-post-soap/2560129#2560129)

Comment: @E.dan: i request that have a look on my question now.I precise it

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper: sorry, the question is really not clear.  What is the URL?  What is the data you want to send?  Is it name/value pairs, or JSON?  What works and what doesn't work?  You are missing the critical details and it's really hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: records fetch from data base and then appending to A string builder and finally i create synData1 string from String builder

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve, but this definitely looks wrong:

```
URL url = new URL(syn_data1.toString());
URLEncoder.encode(syn_data1.toString(),"UTF-16BE");
```

If `syn_data1` is already a string, you don't need to call `toString` on it.. and calling `URLEncoder.encode` doesn't have any side-effects, so the second statement is pointless. Perhaps you want:

```
URL url = new URL(URLEncoder.encode(syn_data1, "UTF-16BE"));
```

That's just on the encoding side though - you still shouldn't be trying to use enormous URLs. If you have a lot of data, that should be in the body of the request rather than the URL.

Comment: i edited and check already but its also not working.I think its related to string size as if it increase more than 6000 it give responce -1

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper: As I've said, you shouldn't be trying to include that much data in the URL. It should be part of a post body. Your server will need to understand that, of course.

Comment: Sorry but i am clear about it.How can i add it to request body in this code. BTW thank you for time Jon :) can you come to chat please if possible

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper: No, I'm busy trying to do my own work. The first thing you'd need to do is make sure that the server can even *cope* with it as a body. After that, using HttpClient seems like a good idea...