# HTTP Put set content type

Tags: java, http, content-type, http-put

How can I set content type of HTTP Put as xxxx+xml?

I was referring to solution in this link [Android, sending XML via HTTP POST (SOAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559948/android-sending-xml-via-http-post-soap). Its fine when we set content type like this, i mean the xml is came along with the request:

```
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");
```

but when i change type **soap** to something custom, the xml disappear on the request (i saw on the wireshark), like this:

```
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/vnd.oma-pcc+xml;charset=UTF-8");
```

then, i tried put the xml only, so the request is ok again:

```
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/xml;charset=UTF-8");
```

I want to know what exactly the rules for the content-type than come together with the xml type so that the xml still there.

Thanks.

Comment: If the MIME type is one of those standardized one, you can use the +xml as you did in the first place. If the you are using custom protocol, you have to supersede it with "vnd" which stands for Vendor.

Comment: i've already put vnd.oma-pcc but still not work. anything i missed?

Comment: adding "vnd" doesn't make it work unless you have a browser that is able to decode a content of that type. Make sure that you add the necessary library to parse that kind of content.

Comment: Umm.., I was execute the request using httpClient.execute(httppost); programmatically using java. Do you have idea how I add the necessary library to parse that content type?

Comment: I think this has to do with the server not recognizing this format as the format of its parameter. If you can access the code in the server check if the POST method is annotated with @Consumes("application/vnd.oma-pcc+xml"). You might be able to debug the program and see what exactly the server is responding that might give you the clue.

Comment: Are you using Apache HTTP Client? this is not overly well indicated.

Comment: @Dave, yes i was using org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
 and using the execute(httpPost);

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using HTTPClient of 4.1.3 or greater -

When constructing you're entity, you have the option to specify the content being used for the POST or PUT operation for certain entities.

There is a [ContentType](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/ContentType.html) object which should be used to specify this.

Using the factory method .create() you can specify the mimetype with a charset - the ContentType will be used by the framework to properly emit the header in question.

Example API call:

`ContentType.create("application/vnd.oma-pcc+xml", CharSet.forName("UTF-8"));`

**NOTE Editing for HttpClient 4.1.2**

In the case of 4.1.2, when you create your entity for the post or put operation, set the content type on the ***entity*** not the ***execution*** (HttpPost or HttpPut) using setContentType(String).  This is deprecated in 4.1.3 and beyond.

Comment: oh.., unfortune i use version 4.1.2, but i see there is httpmime-4.1.2.jar. now i investigating if it can help me.

Comment: @dejoong - I don't believe that httpmime is needed - that API is in the standard httpclient jar