# Connection my app to a WCF Service

Tags: java, .net, android

Iam working on a app and I need to send data from my database, As I have udnerstood arch of android, I must use REST service. I have tried finding information but I can't. I have tryied with books, and none of the are showing how to connect the services, and how to create WCF service in asp.net.

PLS.
Help me out

Answer (score 1):

Nizam:

Here is a starter kit for WCF-REST:
http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/wcf-rest

And here is a tutorial for creating a WCF-REST service:
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/310747.aspx

Accessing these from your application should be pretty simple.  There is already a question at SO with many responses: [How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links.. I have installed the preview, and I owunder which one should I use: REst Singeltone or Collection?