# What are the best practices to design webservices for mobile (particularly Android) apps?

Tags: android, web-services

What are the best practices to design webservices for mobile (particularly Android) apps?
Personally I'm focused on using JSON (and not XML) and I try to make it the less verbose I can. But I'm probably missing a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

The stuff I've read so far indicates that there is too much of a processing overhead when calling a traditional webservice using SOAP and parsing xml. The best advice was to make your webservice RESTful and use JSON. There's some good information on this earlier question:
[How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android)

Answer (score 0):

XML parsing on Android is supposed to be faster than the built-in JSON parser as the former is backed by native code. However, some people have used a different JSON parser (http://jackson.codehaus.org/) with success.

Answer (score 0):

The [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) parser also works well with Android in my experience. Given that a shot if you're sending / received JSON payloads.