# How to use sharepoint webservice in android?

Tags: android

I want to use Sharepoint webservice in android.i don't know how to start.
Anyone help me..

Comment: you might get a better answer if your question was more specific. what sharepoint webservice operation do want to use? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to create some wat like a dash board.. here i want to access a sharepoint webservice which contains NTLM authentication from our android application.. i cant able to over come tat NTLM problem.. is there any solutions ??????

Answer (score 0):

In general, you'll want to open an [HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297068/how-to-read-full-data-using-httpurlconnection-in-android), set it up for a POST or GET to the appropriate URL, and then send the request and read the response.

or you could use [DefaultHttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android).