# How to use OCR web service in android application. How can we send request and get response?

Tags: android, web-services, ocr

How can we use OCR web service in android application
I have use this webservice. 
How can i pass data using soap base web service and get response back.
How can i pass request for nested XML tags ?

http://www.ocrwebservice.com/services/OCRWebService.asmx?op=OCRWebServiceRecognize

Please help..

Comment: I want to point out another possibility: The WiseTrend OCR API at  http://www.wisetrend.com/wisetrend_ocr_cloud.shtml - it's a REST API so should be much easier to use, and it uses the ABBYY OCR engine which is great for low-quality images (like those from mobile phone cameras). (Disclaimer: WiseTrend is my company's customer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i got the correct answer. For nested request i wrote the below code and it worked.

```
   SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

  // Add input values to SOAPObject object - request
        request.addProperty("user_name", "test");
        request.addProperty("license_code",
                "test");
 // Add property for nested tags        
        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();

        pi.setName("OCRWSSetting");
        pi.setValue(new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "OCRWSSettings")
        .addProperty("ocrLanguages", "ENGLISH")
        .addProperty("outputDocumentFormat", "TXT")
        .addProperty("convertToBW", false)
        .addProperty("getOCRText", true)
        .addProperty("createOutputDocument", false)
        .addProperty("multiPageDoc", false)
        .addProperty("ocrWords", false));

        request.addProperty(pi);

    // Add property for another nested tags 

        pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("OCRWSInputImage");
        pi.setValue(new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "OCRWSInputImage")
        .addProperty("fileName", getString(R.string.file_name))
        .addProperty("fileData",base64String)
        );

        request.addProperty(pi);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check this library for Android: [kSoap2](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/).

Also, check this similar question, that offers a few other solutions: "[How to call web service with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android)"

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but actually i know how to use webservice with android. My question was regarding nested tags request that we have to pass.