# How to post values to webservice in android

Tags: android

I want to get some clues about posting the values to the webservice...

When i post the values, i get the response in xml that has to be parsed. Any tutorials of posting the values to webservice will be of great help...

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44302488/4116560). Its easy when you use REST webservice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a useful tutorial on interacting with a REST service: https://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/. If the service is a SOAP service, then take a look at the Stack Overflow question [How to call web service with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/297586/196844).

As far as XML parsing, I wrote an Android app for which I also needed to parse XML. For my purpose, I found that the [`XmlPullParser`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) API was the most convenient: [How to use XmlPullParser in Android](https://web.archive.org/web/20210117122522/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/05/how-to-use-xmlpullparser-in-android.html)

One thing to note is that the Android 3.x and earlier implementation of `XmlPullParser` (from the Apache Harmony project) does not support [`getPrefix()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#getPrefix%28%29) or [`getAttributePrefix(int index)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#getAttributePrefix%28int%29). Beginning with Android 4.0, the `XmlPullParser` implementation switched to [kXML2](https://kxml.sourceforge.net/). I am not sure whether kXML2 supports the `getPrefix()` and `getAttributePrefix(int)` methods.

Answer (score 2):

https://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/

The above link provides a good example of a class you can use to call a REST webservice, both with and without parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this question is pretty old, but I thought I would add this for anyone else that comes along.

The lukencode.com provided above works, but it runs on the main thread and blocks, so it can cause the dreaded "Application Not Responding" error from Android.  There is a similar solution available that breaks it out onto it's own thread so it can run asynchronously without blocking here.

[Rest service wrapper](http://10son.posterous.com/restservice-simple-wrapper-for-android-rest-r)