# Regarding connection between sqlserver 2005 and android application

Tags: android, web-services

i want to connect sqlserver 2005 with the android application. i came to know that webservice is required to connect. but i dont know how to create webservice and dont have any idea of creating it. can please anyone help me with the source code or any related articles regarding it.

hope to hear soon.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very specific, hence you might receive downvotes. 
These tutorials are found in the first page of a google search:

- http://www.slideshare.net/sullis/connecting-to-web-services-on-android
- [How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android)

Web services are nothing else than data input and output, so you might have to start reading here even: [Send string from Android phone to PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546872/send-string-from-android-phone-to-pc-over-wifi).

Answer (score 1):

u can use apache axis2 and soap to connect any database...

try to read and undrstand tutorials on net.....

http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/install.html#ThingsYouHaveToKnow-