# How to connect Android to PC using Wifi?

Tags: c#, android, tcp, xamarin.android

Hello everybody if I want to write app use mono for android by have 2 box for add IP-address,TCP  2 button for ok button

I don't know process for connect Android to PC using Wifi by add IP-address and TCP/IP

Anyone who can give some ideas about it will be great anyone please suggest me any idea for this so that it will be very helpful to me. Thanks in advance!!

I can't post picture but this is link for support my questions

http://sdrv.ms/17ZlOk3

Comment: android.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DeeMac: android.stackexchange isn't for development questions.

Comment: You may find useful this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Comment: @Poldie - fair enough. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chech out the links..

[WiFi connection via android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443245/wifi-connection-via-android)

[how to Send string from Android to PC over wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388250/how-to-send-string-from-android-to-pc-over-wifi)

[Send string from Android phone to PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546872/send-string-from-android-phone-to-pc-over-wifi)

http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html

You can get some idea..

Comment: Don't post link-only answer plz