# Android and data.gov

Tags: java, android, soap

I'm getting ready to start my first app, and I wanted to grab some data from exposed webservices at data.gov.  However, it seems that all the web services they offer are SOAP based.

I cruised [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android) question and I don't want to use ksoap2 if the overall community isn't happy with it.  That question is also almost 2 years old, and something might exist now that I didn't find via google.  (which is only ksoap2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That question is also almost 2 years
>   old, and something might exist now
>   that I didn't find via google.

Well, the only news I can give you that, ksoap2 has a light weight Android porting now:

[ksoap2-android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/)

> I don't want to use ksoap2 if the
>   overall community isn't happy with it.

What are you talking about? Many Android developers I know are working with `ksoap2-android`, AFAIK. 
What news source did you use to get this impression?

Comment: My impression reading the responses to the previous question was that some programmers weren't happy with ksoap2.  Knowing that SOAP is processor-intensive I was worried about that too;  but if there's an android-specific library I'll need to take a look at it.