# Creating Web Services for Android Application

Tags: android, web-services, for-loop

I am new to creating WebServices for Android Application using eclipse,can i create webservices or not if it is possible please let me know the step how to create that steps.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of: [how-to-call-web-service-with-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android)

Answer (score 2):

WebServices are written on the server side. you use any server side scripting language like PHP/JSP/ASP or whatever, to write them.

I don't think there's any dependency related to Android.

You just create a script that caters any need of data from your Android device (and your app), you request that script from you app, that script replies back. that's it.

Further you may use SOAP/WSDL or REST for it

Comment: Your android app need to hit the URL and parse it accordingly.
If Web service reply in xml format . use XML Parser e.g SAXParser
Or If any other format response use StreamReader say BufferedReader

Comment: I won't call it a dependency. Since XML/JSON are common formats websites (whether on REST or SOAP) reply. facilities for paring both are very well available in Android. and in all cases, one can always create their own parser.

Answer (score 0):

its not posible ever.you are creating app. not website so you can use webservice.You can use webservice through android