# Use Web Service in Android

Tags: android

I want to use the web service in Android Application. I have already built web service using SOAP.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try if [KSOAP2](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/) library meets your needs, since it is more suited to mobile devices than libraries aimed for PCs

Comment: Where can i find best KSOAP tutorial.

Comment: Here are some [link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data), [link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9b246db7d612a6b5/44bb777f03c5c8ac?pli=1)

Comment: Prepare for war if you'd like to use kSoap for any scenarios more complex than adding two numbers together with a soap-service tho.

Comment: i found solution. It worked using ksoap2...

Answer (score 0):

You can use existing Java libraries in Android. Check out Apache's Axis: http://axis.apache.org/axis/ as an example of a SOAP Java library.

Also, this is a duplicate of this SA question:
[How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android)

Comment: I have used Apache Axis2 for building web service. But the problem is how can i call that web service in android.

Comment: I have used KSOAP2 for calling web service in android....it worked smoothly..