# Webservice Android

Tags: asp.net, android

I have a asp.net Webservice which returns me XML. What should i use in Android and how to parse?

Comment: Have you at least tried to use Google?

Comment: The problem is in google i find ksoap,rest,json, etc. and i dont get the best overview whats the best for me now!

Comment: I thing kSoap is best whether the webservice is in dotnet or java.

Comment: Try this Url :
[http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data)

Comment: You can try android-ws-client [http://code.google.com/p/android-ws-client/](http://code.google.com/p/android-ws-client/)

Answer (score 2):

Is your WS SOAP based or RESTful?

These threads [Invoking WEbService from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android/1940991#1940991) and [Working with XML on Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) might help you get started.

Comment: How can i find that out? I only know that i get xml files?

Comment: A quick check would be to see if responses are SOAP messages(XML tags containing <soap...:> prefix). If they are normal XML(no soap namespace) then the webservice is RESTful.

Comment: Okay, no SOAP. So i cant use kSoap2 library? Can i get soap messages instead of only xml?

Comment: why would you want to do that? Connect to the remote server using DefaultHTTPClient and parse the response XML using XML Pull parser.

Comment: Are you communicating via formatted URLS, or if you're testing in VS,  are you doing it by going into VS and saying "Import Web Service"...something like that. If the former its probably some REST variant, if the latter, then probably SOAP. If it is soap you shouldn't have to access the XML at all, VS should generate code to marshal everything to objects in the language of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

In order to parse the XML please use [kSoap2](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) library. Also check this [post](http://www.drdobbs.com/article/printableArticle.jhtml;jsessionid=CC35KOEIFLE31QE1GHPCKHWATMY32JVN?articleId=208800166&dept_url=/mobility/)