# get message from web service in android

Tags: android, web-services

I have developed android application named VMS.I have to get messages from the webservice.The url is http://194.22.19.105/vmsc/vmsc.asmx?op=GetMessages

Can anyone guide me how to proceed with this webservice

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out this question: [How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android)

Comment: I have looked into this,,But got no idea,,

Comment: Dude read the whole thing, they're proposing many SOAP libraries for android so you can manage to get a message from a webservice.